# WP shortcode output always at top of page

Tags: wordpress, return, buffer, echo, shortcode

When placing a shortcode on a custom WordPress page the output is always displayed at the top of my page content.

I found out that the problem can be fixed by either using return instead of echo, or [by using output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591351/8496190):  `(ob_start() / ob_get_contents())`

Unfortunately my coding skills are not what I would like them to be.. And I don't know exactly where to implement these fixes.

Can someone help me out please? The plugin developer is not responding to my mails and I need to get this to work a.s.a.p.

I assume this needs to be implemented in the faulty plugin's functions file so I added it below.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Woocommerce Category Accordion Functions
 *
 * @author   TechieResource
 * @category  Shortcode
 * @package  woocommerce-category-accordion/inc
 * @version  1.2.1
 */
 /**
 
 /* Clean variables
 *
 * @param string $var
 * @return string
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
} // Exit if accessed directly

if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
  
class trwca_wc_category_accordion{
 
  /**
   * Constructor
   */
     private $shortcode_tag = "WC-Category-Accordion";
   
  public function __construct() {
  
  add_action( 'woocommerce_category_accordion', array( $this, 'woocommerce_category_accordion_func' ), 10, 2 );
  add_shortcode( $this->shortcode_tag, array( $this, 'wc_category_accordion_sc' ) );
  
   if ( is_admin() ){
    add_action('admin_head', array( $this, 'admin_head') );
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this , 'admin_enqueue_scripts' ) );
   }
  }


  /**
   * Display the Woocommerce Category Accordion.
   * @since  1.2.1
   * @param  array $instance Arguments.
   * @param  bool  $echo Whether to display or return the output.
   * @return string
   */
  public function woocommerce_category_accordion_func( $instance, $echo = true ) {

   extract( $instance, EXTR_SKIP );

   global $wp_query;  
  
   global $post, $product; 
 
   $exclude_tree   = esc_attr($exclude_tree );  
  
   $hide_empty     = esc_attr($hide_empty );
   
   $show_count     = esc_attr($show_count ); 
   
   $open_cat       = esc_attr($open_cat );  
   
   $ac_speed       = esc_attr($ac_speed );
   
   $ac_type        = esc_attr($ac_type );
   
   $event_type     = esc_attr($event_type );
   
   $ac_icon        = esc_attr($ac_icon );
   
   $sortby         = esc_attr($sortby );
   
   $ac_theme       = esc_attr($ac_theme ); 
    
   $order          = esc_attr($order );
   
   $level          = esc_attr($level );
   
   $cats_id        = esc_attr($ac_opencat);
   
   $disable_parent = esc_attr($disable_parent);
   
   $disable_aclink = esc_attr($disable_aclink);
     
   if(!empty($instance['id'])){
    
    $widgetid= $instance['id'];
   }
   else{
    if($sh_id!=""){
     $widgetid= "wc_category_accordion-".$sh_id; 
    }
    else{ 
     $widgetid= "wc_category_accordion-".$this->trwca_generate_random_code(3);
    }

   }
  
   $instance_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', '&parent=0&exclude='.$exclude_tree.'');  
    
   if (is_array($instance_categories)) {
 
    foreach($instance_categories as $categories) {
 
      $term_id[] = $categories->term_id;
 
      $term_name = $categories->name;
    }
   }
 
   if(!empty($post->ID)){
    
    $terms =get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
   }
   else {
   
    $terms="";
   }
   
   if (is_array($terms )) {
 
    foreach ( $terms as $term) {
 
     $_cat=$term->term_id;
 
     break;
 
    }
   }
  
          /* For current category highlight */ 
   if(is_product()){
   
   $current_cat= array();
   
   $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();  
     
   if (!empty($cat->term_id))
 
   {
    $current_cat = $cat->term_id;
 
   }
    else{                
     $_cat_id="1";
 
     if (isset($term->term_id))
 
     {
        $_cat=$term->term_id;
 
        $_cat_id = !empty($_cat) ? $_cat_id=$_cat : $_cat_id=1 ;
       
     }
     if (is_shop())
 
     {
      $_cat_id="1";
     }
     if (!is_shop()){
      
      if (is_array($terms )) {     
     
       foreach($terms as $term){
        $myterms[]= $term->term_id; 
       }
       $cats_id=end($myterms); 
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  var cats_id= <?php  return end($myterms); ?>;
 
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
<?php foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat')) as $term) {
    $myterms= $term->term_id;
    return 'ul.'.$widgetid.' li.cat-item-'.$myterms.' > a{font-weight:bold;}';
     }
     }
    }
?>
 </style>
<?php             
 }
   }
 $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
      
  if (!empty($cat->term_id) && !is_product() ){
   
   $cats_id = $cat->term_id;
   return '<script type="text/javascript">
   
   var cats_id= '.$cats_id.';
   
   </script>';
  }
  else if(!is_product_category() && !is_product()){
 
     $cats_id=$ac_opencat;
  }
  $ac_type = $ac_type=="toggle" ? $ac_type= "true" : $ac_type= "false";
  
  $open_cat = $open_cat== true || $open_cat =='on' ? $open_cat=true : $open_cat=false;
     
   

/* Icon Selection */

 switch ($ac_icon) {
   case 'angle' :     
    $open_icon="angle-down";    
    $close_icon="angle-right";
    break;
    
   case 'doubleangle' :
    $open_icon="angle-double-down";
    $close_icon="angle-double-right";
    break;
    
   case 'arrow-circle1' :
    $open_icon="arrow-circle-down";
    $close_icon="arrow-circle-right";
    break;
     
   case 'arrow-circle2' :     
    $open_icon="arrow-circle-o-down";    
    $close_icon="arrow-circle-o-right";
    break;
    
   case 'arrow-right' :
    $open_icon="arrow-down";
    $close_icon="arrow-right";
    break;
    
   case 'caret' :
    $open_icon="caret-down";
    $close_icon="caret-right";
    break;
   
   case 'caret-square' :     
    $open_icon="caret-square-o-down";    
    $close_icon="caret-square-o-right";
    break;
    
   case 'chevron' :
    $open_icon="chevron-down";
    $close_icon="chevron-right";
    break;
    
   case 'chevron-circle' :
    $open_icon="chevron-circle-down";
    $close_icon="chevron-circle-right";
    break;
    
   case 'hand' :
    $open_icon="hand-o-down";
    $close_icon="hand-o-right";
    break;
    
   case 'plus' :
    $open_icon="minus";
    $close_icon="plus";
    break;
    
   case 'plus-circle' :
    $open_icon="minus-circle";
    $close_icon="plus-circle";
    break;
   
   case 'plus-square1' :
    $open_icon="minus-square";
    $close_icon="plus-square";
    break;
    
   case 'plus-square2' :
    $open_icon="minus-square-o";
    $close_icon="plus-square-o";
    break;      
 }
 
 
 if($disable_aclink==true){
  
  $disable_aclink='true';
 }
 else if($disable_aclink==""){
 
  $disable_aclink= 'false';
 }
 if($disable_parent==true){
  
  $disable_parent='true';
 }
 else if($disable_parent==""){
 
  $disable_parent='false';
 
 }
 $cats_id= empty($cats_id) ? 1 : $cats_id;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $=jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function($){ 
$('.<?php echo $widgetid; ?>').trwcAccordion({
   classParent  : 'trwca-parent',
   classActive  : 'active',
   classArrow  : 'trwca-icon',
   classCount  : 'trwca-count',
   classExpand  : 'trwca-current-parent',
   eventType  : '<?php echo $event_type; ?>',
   hoverDelay  : 100,
   menuClose     : true,
   cats_id:  <?php echo $cats_id; ?>,
   ac_type    : <?php echo $ac_type; ?>,
   autoExpand  : true,
   speed        : '<?php echo $ac_speed ?>',
   saveState  : '<?php echo $open_cat; ?>',
   disableLink  : <?php echo $disable_aclink; ?>,
   disableparentLink : <?php echo $disable_parent;  ?>,
   auto_open: 1,
   showCount : true,
   widget_id : "<?php  echo $widgetid; ?>",
   openIcon : '<?php echo $open_icon; ?>',
   closeIcon : '<?php echo $close_icon; ?>',
});
});
</script>
<div class="block-content trwca-actheme <?php echo $ac_theme; ?>">
<div class="trwca-loader"></div>
<ul class="<?php echo $widgetid; ?> accordion" id="outer_ul">
<?php 

$subcat_args = array(

       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'title_li' => '',
       'orderby' => $sortby,
       'order'    => $order,
       'depth' => $level,
       'show_count' => $show_count,
       'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
       'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
       'echo' => false,
       'exclude'  => $exclude_tree,
       'hierarchical' => true ,
       'show_option_none'   => __('No Categories Found','trwca'),
       'link_after' => '',
       'walker'=> new trwca_walker
      );
        
?>
<?php $subcategories = wp_list_categories( $subcat_args );

   $subcategories=preg_replace_callback(
            '/<\/a> \(([0-9]+)\)/',
            function ($matches) {
                return '&nbsp;<span class="count">('.($matches[1]).')</span></a>';
            },$subcategories
        );
  
?>
<?php if ( $subcategories ) {

   echo $subcategories;

            } 
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php

  }
  public function trwca_generate_random_code($length=3) {

        $string = '';
      
    $characters = "123456789";

       for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
         $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
      }

     return $string;

  }
  /**
   * admin_head
   * calls your functions into the correct filters
   * @return void
   */
  function admin_head() {
   // check user permissions
   if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
    return;
   }
   
   // check if WYSIWYG is enabled
   if ( 'true' == get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', array( $this ,'mce_external_plugins' ) );
    add_filter( 'mce_buttons', array($this, 'mce_buttons' ) );
   }
  }
 
  /**
   * mce_external_plugins 
   * Adds our tinymce plugin
   * @param  array $plugin_array 
   * @return array
   */
  function mce_external_plugins( $plugin_array ) {
   
   $plugin_array['WC_Category_Accordion'] = plugins_url( 'admin/js/mce-button.js' , __FILE__ );
   return $plugin_array;
  }
 
  /**
   * mce_buttons 
   * Adds our tinymce button
   * @param  array $buttons 
   * @return array
   */
  function mce_buttons( $buttons ) {
   array_push( $buttons, 'WC_Category_Accordion' );
   return $buttons;
  }
 
  /**
   * admin_enqueue_scripts 
   * Used to enqueue custom styles
   * @return void
   */
  function admin_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style('WC-Category-Accordion-sh', plugins_url( 'admin/css/mce-button.css' , __FILE__ ) );
  }
  public function wc_category_accordion_sc( $atts, $content = null ) {
    
    $defaults = array( 
       'show_count' => 0,
       'ac_speed' => 'fast',
       'exclude_tree' =>'',
       'hide_empty' => 0,
       'sortby' =>'name',
       'order' =>'ASC',
       'level' => 0,
       'event_type' => 'click',
       'ac_type' => 'toggle',
       'open_cat' => 0,
       'ac_opencat' => 1,
       'ac_icon' =>'plus',
       'disable_parent' => 0,
       'disable_aclink' => 0,
       'ac_theme' => '',
       'sh_id'=> '' );
    $settings = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts );
    return $this->woocommerce_category_accordion_func( $settings, false );
  }
}
new trwca_wc_category_accordion();
 
 function trwca_clean( $var ) {
  return sanitize_text_field( $var );
 }
}
?>
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Did my answer fix the problem Affi?

Answer (score 4):

```
function your_shortcode_function(){
ob_start(); ?>
<div>
 // all your stuffs here
</div>
<?php
$contents=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $contents;
}
add_shortcode('your_shortcode', 'your_shortcode_function');
```

You need ob_start and ob_end_clean() as said as above [OUTPUT BUFFERING](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=output%20buffering)

Comment: The problem is in a plugin I bought.. I don't know where the output buffering starts or ends in the script.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use ob_start() and return ob_get_clean() inside the shortcode function.
Likeso:

```
<?php 
function my_shortcode(){ // The function that is our shortode output.
ob_start();?>

<div class="my-shortcode-output">
  <em>I'm <strong>the best</strong></em>
</div>

<?php
return $ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'my_shortcode' );
```

I'd also consider not echoing js from your php, using wp_enque_script and wp_localize_script is much nicer.

Comment: The problem is in a plugin I bought.. I don't know where the output buffering starts or ends in the script.

Comment: Can you please show me where to place this in my code? This issue is taking me more time than needed. Should be an easy fix for someone with your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<?php
/**
 * Woocommerce Category Accordion Functions
 *
 * @author      TechieResource
 * @category    Shortcode
 * @package     woocommerce-category-accordion/inc
 * @version     1.2.1
 */
/**

/* Clean variables
*
* @param string $var
* @return string
*/
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
} // Exit if accessed directly

if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {

    class trwca_wc_category_accordion
    {

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        private $shortcode_tag = "WC-Category-Accordion";

        public function __construct()
        {

            add_action('woocommerce_category_accordion', array(
                $this,
                'woocommerce_category_accordion_func'
            ), 10, 2);
            add_shortcode($this->shortcode_tag, array(
                $this,
                'wc_category_accordion_sc'
            ));

            if (is_admin()) {
                add_action('admin_head', array(
                    $this,
                    'admin_head'
                ));
                add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array(
                    $this,
                    'admin_enqueue_scripts'
                ));
            }
        }


        /**
         * Display the Woocommerce Category Accordion.
         * @since  1.2.1
         * @param  array $instance Arguments.
         * @param  bool  $echo Whether to display or return the output.
         * @return string
         */
        public function woocommerce_category_accordion_func($instance, $echo = true)
        {
            ob_start();

            extract($instance, EXTR_SKIP);

            global $wp_query;

            global $post, $product;

            $exclude_tree = esc_attr($exclude_tree);

            $hide_empty = esc_attr($hide_empty);

            $show_count = esc_attr($show_count);

            $open_cat = esc_attr($open_cat);

            $ac_speed = esc_attr($ac_speed);

            $ac_type = esc_attr($ac_type);

            $event_type = esc_attr($event_type);

            $ac_icon = esc_attr($ac_icon);

            $sortby = esc_attr($sortby);

            $ac_theme = esc_attr($ac_theme);

            $order = esc_attr($order);

            $level = esc_attr($level);

            $cats_id = esc_attr($ac_opencat);

            $disable_parent = esc_attr($disable_parent);

            $disable_aclink = esc_attr($disable_aclink);

            if (!empty($instance['id'])) {

                $widgetid = $instance['id'];
            } else {
                if ($sh_id != "") {
                    $widgetid = "wc_category_accordion-" . $sh_id;
                } else {
                    $widgetid = "wc_category_accordion-" . $this->trwca_generate_random_code(3);
                }

            }

            $instance_categories = get_terms('product_cat', '&parent=0&exclude=' . $exclude_tree . '');

            if (is_array($instance_categories)) {

                foreach ($instance_categories as $categories) {

                    $term_id[] = $categories->term_id;

                    $term_name = $categories->name;
                }
            }

            if (!empty($post->ID)) {

                $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
            } else {

                $terms = "";
            }

            if (is_array($terms)) {

                foreach ($terms as $term) {

                    $_cat = $term->term_id;

                    break;

                }
            }

            /* For current category highlight */
            if (is_product()) {

                $current_cat = array();

                $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

                if (!empty($cat->term_id)) {
                    $current_cat = $cat->term_id;

                } else {
                    $_cat_id = "1";

                    if (isset($term->term_id)) {
                        $_cat = $term->term_id;

                        $_cat_id = !empty($_cat) ? $_cat_id = $_cat : $_cat_id = 1;

                    }
                    if (is_shop()) {
                        $_cat_id = "1";
                    }
                    if (!is_shop()) {

                        if (is_array($terms)) {

                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                $myterms[] = $term->term_id;
                            }
                            $cats_id = end($myterms);
                            ?>
                                <script type="text/javascript">

                                 var cats_id= <?php
                            return end($myterms);
                            ?>;

                                </script>
                                <style type="text/css">
                            <?php
                            foreach ((get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat')) as $term) {
                                $myterms = $term->term_id;
                                return 'ul.' . $widgetid . ' li.cat-item-' . $myterms . ' > a{font-weight:bold;}';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                            ?>
                                </style>
                            <?php
                }
            }
            $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

            if (!empty($cat->term_id) && !is_product()) {

                $cats_id = $cat->term_id;
                return '<script type="text/javascript">

            var cats_id= ' . $cats_id . ';

            </script>';
            } else if (!is_product_category() && !is_product()) {

                $cats_id = $ac_opencat;
            }
            $ac_type = $ac_type == "toggle" ? $ac_type = "true" : $ac_type = "false";

            $open_cat = $open_cat == true || $open_cat == 'on' ? $open_cat = true : $open_cat = false;



            /* Icon Selection */

            switch ($ac_icon) {
                case 'angle':
                    $open_icon  = "angle-down";
                    $close_icon = "angle-right";
                    break;

                case 'doubleangle':
                    $open_icon  = "angle-double-down";
                    $close_icon = "angle-double-right";
                    break;

                case 'arrow-circle1':
                    $open_icon  = "arrow-circle-down";
                    $close_icon = "arrow-circle-right";
                    break;

                case 'arrow-circle2':
                    $open_icon  = "arrow-circle-o-down";
                    $close_icon = "arrow-circle-o-right";
                    break;

                case 'arrow-right':
                    $open_icon  = "arrow-down";
                    $close_icon = "arrow-right";
                    break;

                case 'caret':
                    $open_icon  = "caret-down";
                    $close_icon = "caret-right";
                    break;

                case 'caret-square':
                    $open_icon  = "caret-square-o-down";
                    $close_icon = "caret-square-o-right";
                    break;

                case 'chevron':
                    $open_icon  = "chevron-down";
                    $close_icon = "chevron-right";
                    break;

                case 'chevron-circle':
                    $open_icon  = "chevron-circle-down";
                    $close_icon = "chevron-circle-right";
                    break;

                case 'hand':
                    $open_icon  = "hand-o-down";
                    $close_icon = "hand-o-right";
                    break;

                case 'plus':
                    $open_icon  = "minus";
                    $close_icon = "plus";
                    break;

                case 'plus-circle':
                    $open_icon  = "minus-circle";
                    $close_icon = "plus-circle";
                    break;

                case 'plus-square1':
                    $open_icon  = "minus-square";
                    $close_icon = "plus-square";
                    break;

                case 'plus-square2':
                    $open_icon  = "minus-square-o";
                    $close_icon = "plus-square-o";
                    break;
            }


            if ($disable_aclink == true) {

                $disable_aclink = 'true';
            } else if ($disable_aclink == "") {

                $disable_aclink = 'false';
            }
            if ($disable_parent == true) {

                $disable_parent = 'true';
            } else if ($disable_parent == "") {

                $disable_parent = 'false';

            }
            $cats_id = empty($cats_id) ? 1 : $cats_id;
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var $=jQuery.noConflict();
            $(document).ready(function($){  
            $('.<?php
                        echo $widgetid;
            ?>').trwcAccordion({
                        classParent  : 'trwca-parent',
                        classActive  : 'active',
                        classArrow   : 'trwca-icon',
                        classCount   : 'trwca-count',
                        classExpand  : 'trwca-current-parent',
                        eventType    : '<?php
                        echo $event_type;
            ?>',
                        hoverDelay   : 100,
                        menuClose     : true,
                        cats_id:  <?php
                        echo $cats_id;
            ?>,
                        ac_type    : <?php
                        echo $ac_type;
            ?>,
                        autoExpand   : true,
                        speed        : '<?php
                        echo $ac_speed;
            ?>',
                        saveState    : '<?php
                        echo $open_cat;
            ?>',
                        disableLink  : <?php
                        echo $disable_aclink;
            ?>,
                        disableparentLink : <?php
                        echo $disable_parent;
            ?>,
                        auto_open: 1,
                        showCount : true,
                        widget_id : "<?php
                        echo $widgetid;
            ?>",
                        openIcon    : '<?php
                        echo $open_icon;
            ?>',
                        closeIcon   : '<?php
                        echo $close_icon;
            ?>',
            });
            });
            </script>
            <div class="block-content trwca-actheme <?php
                        echo $ac_theme;
            ?>">
            <div class="trwca-loader"></div>
            <ul class="<?php
                        echo $widgetid;
            ?> accordion" id="outer_ul">
            <?php

            $subcat_args = array(

                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'title_li' => '',
                'orderby' => $sortby,
                'order' => $order,
                'depth' => $level,
                'show_count' => $show_count,
                'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
                'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
                'echo' => false,
                'exclude' => $exclude_tree,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'show_option_none' => __('No Categories Found', 'trwca'),
                'link_after' => '',
                'walker' => new trwca_walker
            );


            $subcategories = wp_list_categories($subcat_args);

            $subcategories = preg_replace_callback('/<\/a> \(([0-9]+)\)/', function($matches)
            {
                return '&nbsp;<span class="count">(' . ($matches[1]) . ')</span></a>';
            }, $subcategories);

            if ($subcategories) {

                echo $subcategories;

            }
            ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <?php
            $contents=ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $contents;                
        }

        public function trwca_generate_random_code($length = 3)
        {

            $string = '';

            $characters = "123456789";

            for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
                $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
            }

            return $string;

        }
        /**
         * admin_head
         * calls your functions into the correct filters
         * @return void
         */
        function admin_head()
        {
            // check user permissions
            if (!current_user_can('edit_posts') && !current_user_can('edit_pages')) {
                return;
            }

            // check if WYSIWYG is enabled
            if ('true' == get_user_option('rich_editing')) {
                add_filter('mce_external_plugins', array(
                    $this,
                    'mce_external_plugins'
                ));
                add_filter('mce_buttons', array(
                    $this,
                    'mce_buttons'
                ));
            }
        }

        /**
         * mce_external_plugins 
         * Adds our tinymce plugin
         * @param  array $plugin_array 
         * @return array
         */
        function mce_external_plugins($plugin_array)
        {

            $plugin_array['WC_Category_Accordion'] = plugins_url('admin/js/mce-button.js', __FILE__);
            return $plugin_array;
        }

        /**
         * mce_buttons 
         * Adds our tinymce button
         * @param  array $buttons 
         * @return array
         */
        function mce_buttons($buttons)
        {
            array_push($buttons, 'WC_Category_Accordion');
            return $buttons;
        }

        /**
         * admin_enqueue_scripts 
         * Used to enqueue custom styles
         * @return void
         */
        function admin_enqueue_scripts()
        {
            wp_enqueue_style('WC-Category-Accordion-sh', plugins_url('admin/css/mce-button.css', __FILE__));
        }
        public function wc_category_accordion_sc($atts, $content = null)
        {

            $defaults = array(
                'show_count' => 0,
                'ac_speed' => 'fast',
                'exclude_tree' => '',
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'sortby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'level' => 0,
                'event_type' => 'click',
                'ac_type' => 'toggle',
                'open_cat' => 0,
                'ac_opencat' => 1,
                'ac_icon' => 'plus',
                'disable_parent' => 0,
                'disable_aclink' => 0,
                'ac_theme' => '',
                'sh_id' => ''
            );
            $settings = shortcode_atts($defaults, $atts);
            return $this->woocommerce_category_accordion_func($settings, false);
        }
    }
    new trwca_wc_category_accordion();

    function trwca_clean($var)
    {
        return sanitize_text_field($var);
    }
}
?>
```