# Render HTML properly from Wordpress Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a shortcode which renders this table on the frontend. At the moment the shortcode puts the content at the top of the page rather than respecting the location of where the shortcode is pasted in the editor.

How can i fix this?

```
<div id="cookie-container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h3>Essential Cookies</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm diva-cookie-table">
        <thead class="diva-cookie-table__thead">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 33%" class="diva-cookie-table__th">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 33%" class="diva-cookie-table__th">Cookie</th>
            <th style="width: 33%" class="diva-cookie-table__th">Purpose</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="diva-cookie-table__tbody">
        <tr>
            <?php
            $essential_cookies = carbon_get_theme_option( 'essential_cookies' );
            foreach ( $essential_cookies as $cookie ) {
                echo '<tr>';
                if($cookie['name']) {
                    echo '<td class="diva-cookie-table__title">';
                    echo $cookie['name'];
                    echo '</td>';
                }
                if($cookie['cookies']) {
                    echo '<td class="diva-cookie-table__title">';
                    echo $cookie['cookies'];
                    echo '</td>';
                }
                if($cookie['usage']) {
                    echo '<td class="diva-cookie-table__title">';
                    echo $cookie['usage'];
                    echo '</td>';
                }
            }
            echo '</tr>';
            ?>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

```
/**
 * Construct Essential Cookies Shortcode
 */
function construct_essential_cookies_table()
{

    ob_start();

        include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/partials/essential_cookie_table.php';

    return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode('diva_essential_cookies', 'construct_essential_cookies_table');
```

Comment: Please share your entire shortcode function, not just the HTML portion of it, so we can help out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcode output always showing at top of custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586566/shortcode-output-always-showing-at-top-of-custom-template) or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588554/wordpress-shortcode-is-always-at-the-top-of-the-content/60588756#60588756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the full HTML code inside the php output buffer functions like that.

```
    <?php ob_start(); ?>
        <div id="cookie-container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h3>Essential Cookies</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm diva-cookie-table">
                <thead class="diva-cookie-table__thead">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 33%" class="diva-cookie-table__th">Name</th>
                    <th style="width: 33%" class="diva-cookie-table__th">Cookie</th>
                    <th style="width: 33%" class="diva-cookie-table__th">Purpose</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
        
                <tbody class="diva-cookie-table__tbody">
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    $essential_cookies = carbon_get_theme_option( 'essential_cookies' );
                    foreach ( $essential_cookies as $cookie ) {
                        
                        echo '<tr>';
                        if($cookie['name']) {
                            echo '<td class="diva-cookie-table__title">';
                            echo $cookie['name'];
                            echo '</td>';
                        }
                        if($cookie['cookies']) {
                            echo '<td class="diva-cookie-table__title">';
                            echo $cookie['cookies'];
                            echo '</td>';
                        }
                        if($cookie['usage']) {
                            echo '<td class="diva-cookie-table__title">';
                            echo $cookie['usage'];
                            echo '</td>';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        
        </div>
 <?php return ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: I have added the short code function to the OP, what is the best way to pass the field to the include as i am currently calling it in the include.

Comment: I don't get what field, but If you want to pass a variable to the include template. you can just list the variable before the include statement. like

 $x = 'test';  include 'TEMPLATE_PATH';

 the $x variable will be available inside the included template

Comment: this field is in the include:
$essential_cookies = carbon_get_theme_option( 'essential_cookies' );

I want to put it in the actual function rather than the include

Comment: ok. just put the line  $essential_cookies = carbon_get_theme_option( 'essential_cookies' ); above the include line. It will be accessible inside the template